# After upgrading to nvidia 375, glitchy borders around windows

Tags: nvidia, xorg, suspend, window, cuda

I recently upgraded from `nvidia-370` to `nvidia-375` as part of my efforts to install CUDA/Tensorflow, but I'm now getting a weird bug. Upon resuming from sleep, [image: these glitchy borders] appear around all windows and menu elements.

I've had bugs like this before, but the " press`ctrl + alt + f1` and then `ctrl + alt + f7`" method, which worked with other sleep bugs, doesn't fix this problem. Does anyone know of a solution to this, or is my only option to downgrade to the 370 driver? I'm running 16.04 on kernel 4.4.0-62-generic

Comment: You can only report it as a bug. But this driver is not in the official repos yet.

Comment: For tensorflow, I've had great luck with 367.

Comment: @AndrewKeech oh cool, I think I'll just downgrade to the 370 driver then, that was rock solid. I thought 375 might have been required for `cuda`

Comment: @AndrewKeech actually, when using synaptic to try and remove the 375 drivers, it says that they can't be removed without removal of the `cuda` package as well. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: CUDA depends on the Nvidia drivers. No surprise there. You can later reinstall it when running the new (old) driver.

Comment: Trying to install `nvidia-370` threatens to remove the `cuda` stuff as well as `nvidia-375` though, and installing `cuda` upgrades the graphics drivers. I think `cuda` and `nvidia-375` may be linked somehow

Comment: Same problem here. Is there an official bug-report for this problem or any known fixes?

Comment: Just now updated myself, having the same issue. Has there been a fix found that doesn't involve running `compiz --replace` every time I resume from suspend?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same problem. My driver was updated to `nvidia-375` after upgrading `cuda`.

I found that restarting the window manager with

`unity --replace`

fixed this, although some windows crashed (Chrome for example) in the process.

Restarting compiz mighty also work, though I haven't tried it.

Edit: `compiz --replace` seems to work better for this, with little or no window crashing.

Comment: SInce I posted this, I've upgraded to Zesty and moved to Gnome Shell, since Unity has no future now. Gnome Shell finally seems to be stable under Ubuntu, and ... no more border problems!

Answer (score 1):

Got the same issue with new drivers (378.13).
Try to set old version in System Settings -> Additional Drivers. In my case work fine with 367.57

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here after upgrade nvidia driver to versio 375.39. In case of Intel driver, everything is fine. It's look like nvidia screwd up something. Any solution?

I fixed it by add 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

and install nvidia-370

Answer (score 0):

This bug is already logged on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1667158)
Someone suggested a temporary [fix](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-375/+bug/1667158/comments/13) which worked great for me and that I reproduce here:

Create a file /lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixborders with the editor of your choice with root permissions. (If you don't know, just type `gksudo gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixborders` in a terminal)
with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
kill $(ps -C compiz -o pid=)
```

Give that file excutable permissions:

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/fixborders
```

Et voila!

Comment: Did you forget the kill command in that script?

Comment: The problem with the solution above is that it does bypass the lock screen, so is not ideal. I di not managed to start the locking from the script. So I ended up just calling fixborders.sh manually after resuming...