# Is there a way to install the Cuda toolkit on the 370 drivers?

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, dependencies, cuda

I've been trying to install `tensorflow-gpu`, and as part of that process I need to install the cuda toolkit. [Nvidia's instructions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4VZnqTJ2A) for doing so direct you to download a .deb file and install it, which I dutifully did. Next, they tell you to run `sudo apt-get install cuda`

I did so and the install went without a hitch, but the `cuda` package upgraded my drivers from `nvidia-370` to `nvidia-375`. Now I'm dealing with a [really nasty sleep bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/884046/after-upgrading-to-nvidia-375-glitchy-borders-around-windows) which I assume is the fault of the new drivers. Therefore, I'd like to downgrade my drivers.

However, when I run `sudo apt-get install nvidia-370`, Ubuntu tells me that it will remove not only `nvidia-375`, but `cuda` and all its associated packages as well. And installing the `cuda` package automatically upgrades my graphics drivers.

Has anyone managed to get tensorflow/the cuda library installed on anything but the 375 drivers?

Comment: have you got the graphics-drivers ppa installed? I've pinned mine to 367.57, and installed cuda 8.0.44. Worked on 16.04 and now 16.10. Do you need the 370 series for a Pascal card or something?

Comment: @AndrewKeech I do have the ppa installed. How did you pin your drivers, and how did you install Cuda? I was following nvidia's official instructions @ http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4VZnqTJ2A

Comment: it's "pinned" in the sense that I haven't changed it in the system settings from 367.57. I used the .deb download from nvidia for cuda 8.0.44 (1.9 Gbs), and the cudnn 5.1.5 (39 Mbs), which is another sign-up and download iirc. Tensorflow was installed in a virtualenv, and didn't need any more convincing than that to work with it